# data-bind="click" not working with nested knockout view model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a knockout view model that is set up as an observable as my main view model.  In the child element, it seems that I can't set up `data-bind="click:` the same way that I can when I am in the parent element.

My html:

```
 <button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-bind="click: test">Click Me</button>
```

In my main view model:

```
 self.childElement = ko.observable(new childElementVm());
```

and in `childElementVm`

```
var childElementVm= function () {
    var test = function(){
        alert('this is a test');
    }
}
```

what do I need to do differently to use `data-bind="click: test"` here?
To note, my applyBindings is fine (other knockout observables are functioning correctly) and the button is contained inside of a `<div data-bind="with: childElement"`

EDIT: [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gtdh3aq/3/)

Comment: Can you create fiddle please?

Comment: Your function `test` is private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `test` function is scoped to the `childElementVm`only. Change your implementation to this:

```
var childElementVm= function () {
    this.test = function(){
        alert('this is a test');
    }
}
```

or this:

```
var childElementVm= function () {
    var self = this;
    self.test = function(){
        alert('this is a test');
    }
}
```

Here is a working [example](https://fiddle.jshell.net/aeegjLoL/)

Comment: can you take a look at my fiddle?  why is mine still not working?

Comment: @USER_8675309 You didn't load knockout as an external resource. I've updated it and edited your question with the updated link. It works btw

Comment: thank you so much. I understand now.  I was trying to make it work by doing `data-bind="with: childElement.test"` and what not

Comment: @USER_8675309 no problem buddy, glad I could help : )